# Using vue3-tel-input. Why :defaultCompany prop not setting country

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am using for my form vue3-tel-input. So I want to display phone number(on buttons click make form from view-mode to edit-mode).
I get proper ISO codes from telephone number. Number is got from request.

So the problem is I cannot change defaultCompany in component. So if number is from country A it will show number from country B.

If I make prop dinamic and pass into it variable what contains ISO country code it does nothing at all.
Please help be set default country by ISO code.

Here code itself

```
<vue-tel-input
    :value="phone"
    @input="onInput"
    :defaultCountry="countryISO"
  ></vue-tel-input>

// in code section

data() {
    return {
      phone: "+79991234567",
      countryISO: "AU",
    };
  },
```

here [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/workaround-v-model-with-vue3-tel-input-forked-hrlcjx?file=/src/App.vue)

I am expecting to set default country of vuejs element by dynamic prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone number should be a valid number for that country :

```html
<vue-tel-input
    :value="phone"
    @input="onInput"
    :defaultCountry="countryISO"
  ></vue-tel-input>

// in code section

data() {
    return {
      phone: "+213659451236",
      countryISO: "DZ",
    };
  },
```

or you init `phone` with empty string :

```html
<vue-tel-input
    :value="phone"
    @input="onInput"
    :defaultCountry="countryISO"
  ></vue-tel-input>

// in code section

data() {
    return {
      phone: "",
      countryISO: "PS",
    };
  },
```